# Is this a correct destructor for my Node struct?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have this C++ struct:

```
struct Node {
    char symbol;
    unsigned int index;
    vector<Node*> next;

    // Constructors
    Node():symbol('$'), index(0), next(0) {}
    Node(char &c, const unsigned int &ind):symbol(c), index(ind), next(0) {}

    // Add a new character
    Node* add(char &c, const unsigned int &num) {
        Node *newChar = new Node(c, num);
        next.push_back(newChar);
        return newChar;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Node() {
        for (int i = 0; i < next.size(); i++)
            delete next[i];
    }
};
```

(I know it might be better to make it a class but let's consider it as it is).

I'm not quite sure if I wrote the correct destructor for this. In the main function I'm using a root node:

```
Node *root = new Node();
```

Comment: Is this part of a linked list?  If it is, what if you want to delete a single node instead of unraveling the whole linked list?

Comment: If Node owns all the next pointers, and all of those own their next pointers, and so on, and if nothing else is using any of the objects that any of the pointers point to, then sure, it's correct.

Comment: Since you can create only acyclic trees with your "add", and destructor frees the whole branch for a node, this construction should perfectly work.

Comment: It's not exactly a linked list, it's a trie structure which I see as a tree.

Answer (score 6):

Although the code won't leak memory (as long as you `delete` the root node in `main`), it isn't really optimal.

You should avoid `new` and `delete` and instead prefer smart pointers. In this case, use `unique_ptr`.

Also, don't create the root node on the heap, just create it normally like so:

```
Node root;
// use root normally
```

You also don't follow the rule of five properly, and you won't even need to worry about it if you used `unique_ptr` since you wouldn't have a custom dtor. There's also no reason to take the `c` and `ind` by `ref` and `const ref`, just pass them by value (because you don't even change them, and its as cheap passing by value as by ref for primitives).

With these changes, the code looks like this

```
struct Node {
    char symbol;
    unsigned int index;
    vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> next;

    // Constructors
    Node():symbol('$'), index(0){}
    Node(char c, unsigned int ind):symbol(c), index(ind) {}

    // Add a new character
    Node* add(char c, unsigned int num) {
        next.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(c, num));
        return next.back().get();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for re-writing the code, really appreciate it. I've tried to learn smart pointers multiple times but never found a good tutorial. I'll probably use this example to begin.

Comment: There is a case to be made for `add` returning `Node &` rather than `Node *`. It's a lot harder to oops with a reference without a complaint from the compiler, and if you really do need the address, it's only a `&` away.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree, but I tried to preserve the return type so that the OP understood how to transform from using raw pointers to smart pointers.